# Find the pair (i,j) such that i<j and and (a[i] + a[j]) is maximum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an unsorted array – arr find a pair arr[i] and arr[j] such that 
`arr[i] < arr[j] & i<j` and `(arr[i] + arr[j])` is maximum.

Expected time complexity – `O(n)`

For array `a = {4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3}`

```
pair is (4, 5).
```

Here is the code I've tried..

```
void findPair(int[] a){  
        int n = a.length;
        int max = a[0];
        int secondMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            if(a[i]>max){
                secondMax = max;
                max = a[i];
            }
        }
        if(secondMax == Integer.MIN_VALUE){
            System.out.println("-1 -1");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(secondMax+" "+max);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still remaining: what do we return if there are no solutions, as in `[4,3,2,1]`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using a stack. The idea is that the stack always contains a descending sequence, such that for each number you look at, it can be paired with the largest number in the stack lower than it.

It's safe to pop the numbers off as you use them, because e.g. if you have a 6 and the top of the stack is 3, there is no need to keep the 3 around in case it can be paired with a bigger number; if there's a 7 later, you would wait to pair it with the 6 instead of the 3.

```java
public void solution(int[] arr) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int bestX = -1, bestY = -1, bestSum = -1;

    for(int y : arr) {
        while(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() < y) {
            int x = stack.pop();
            if(x + y > bestSum) { bestX = x; bestY = y; bestSum = x + y; }
        }
        stack.push(y);
    }

    System.out.println(bestX + " " + bestY);
}
```

The time complexity is O(n) despite the nested loop, because the inner loop always pops from the stack, and each element is only pushed once so it can only be popped once.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about your question a lot and I think I found an acceptable solution.

You should split the array into subarrays starting from the end of the array (right side). Building the sub arrays is in iterative manner. You start with the right-most number and you add to the subarray all the numbers *before him* that are *lower than him*. The iteration goes to the next subarray when you reach a number which is bigger/equal to the right-most number in the subarray.

*Example:*

Your array is: {1,7,3,4,5,4,6,2}

Output should be: (5,6)

The splitting should be:

{{1, **7**}, {3, 4, 5, 4, **6**}, {**2**}}

```
  <--(3)     <--(2) <--(1)
```

You start from the last index with the value of 2. The number before him is 6 so that's the end of the first subarray. Next you start with 6, all the numbers before him until 7 are lower than 6 so you add them to that subarray. The last subarray starts with 7 and adds 1. See arrows for clarification.

Next, check within each subarray which number from left to the right-most number is max and mark it for possible pair with the right-most number.

In our example it would be: (1,**7**), (5,**6**).

There are only two options because {2} has only 1 variable. In the subarray with 6 as right-most the max number is 5 and in the subarray with 7 as right-most 1 is the only other number so it is also the max.

If no pair is found, return "no possible pair found".

Finally, check sum and return biggest pair: (5,6)

`1+7 = 8 < 5+6 = 11`

*Why is this `O(n)` ?*

- You scan the array once for splitting: `O(n)`
- Each subarray of size `d` you scan for max value: `O(d)`
- Sum of all subarrays scanning: `O(n)`

Total: `O(n)`

I'm not strong in Java so my code can be written in Python and the conversion should be easy (because Python is easy!). If you wish for Python code, let me know and I'll write some for you. Also, I can explain more why this algorithm works (If not fully understood).

Comment: It is O(n) solution and this would definitely work. I'll write java code. Thanks for telling the approach.

Comment: Thanks. Also, you don't really have to "build" the subarrays. You can just scan for the max number that is also lower than the right-most number.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: Solution is O(n^2), not O(n) as required by the OP**

What about using 2 nested loops:

- `i` from `0` to `a.length`
- `j` from `i+1` to `a.length`

This ensures that `i<j`
Then have an if to ensure that `a[i]<a[j]` and find the max

```
int currentMax = -1;
int foundI = -1;
int foundJ = -1;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
        if(a[i] < a[j] && a[i] + a[j] > currentMax) {
            currentMax = a[i] + a[j];
            foundI = i;
            foundJ = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.out.println("i:" + foundI);
System.out.println("j:" + foundJ);
System.out.println("a[i]:" + a[foundI]);
System.out.println("a[j]:" + a[foundJ]);
System.out.println("sum:" + currentMax);
```

---

```
i:0
j:4
a[i]:4
a[j]:5
sum:9
```

Comment: Thanks but I need an O(n) solution.

Comment: This solution is O(n^2) because it iterates over all pairs of indices where `i < j`.

Comment: @kaya3 ok thanks, I will add a disclaimer at the top of the answer as it can still be useful for somebody finding this thread